# JGIT - skip merges in log

Tags: jgit

Is there any equivalent for "--no-merge" option in log command or any other option to filter logs using JGit? 
Of course, I can check commit message, if it starts from "Merge", but may be it is better way?

I'm doing something like:
https://github.com/centic9/jgit-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dstadler/jgit/porcelain/ShowLog.java

Comment: You could cheeck the parent count, to my knowledge only merge commits have two parents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More than one year have passed by, but I will post an answer for the record.

We are currently in version 4.3 of **JGit**. In this version, you can already use a [`RevWalk#setRevFilter()`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.3.0.201604071810-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/RevWalk.html#setRevFilter(org.eclipse.jgit.revwalk.filter.RevFilter)) and the [`RevFilter.NO_MERGES`](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/site/4.3.0.201604071810-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/revwalk/filter/RevFilter.html#NO_MERGES), which does exactly what you want (report only *non-merges* commits).

```
public void logNonMerges(Repository repo){
   try(RevWalk walk = new RevWalk(repo)) {
      walk.setRevFilter(RevFilter.NO_MERGES);
      Iterator<RevCommit> i = walk.iterator();
      while(i.hasNext()){
         RevCommit commit = i.next();
         // do whatever you want
      }
   }
}
```